# Persist ArrayList<Integer> in greenDao

Tags: java, orm, arraylist, greendao

As the title says how can I add an ArrayList entity to my greenDao models? Official site was no help nor Google. Any help appreciated!

Basically I have a book object and it has an ArrayList field which I would like saved to my database. What would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: Could you please add some more information?

Answer (score 3):

That approach is not common when using relational databases. This is commonly done using to-many relations.

Comment: i am trying to implement this exactly , can you provide any example please ?